# Why is the antiderivative of $f(x)=n^2 x^{n-1}$ not $\frac{1}{3}n^3 \cdot \frac{1}{n}x^n+c$?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve a exercise from my schoolbook.

The question is

> What is the antiderivative of $f(x)=n^2 x^{n-1}$?

I thought it is $\frac{1}{3}n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}x^n+c$, but it actually is $nx^n+c$. I understand why $nx^n+c$ is the right solution; I just don't understand why $\frac{1}{3}n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}x^n+c$ is wrong.

If you want to find the antiderivate of $f(x)=n^2 x^{n-1}$, I thought you could do it this way:

**(Sorry; I don't know which sign to use to indicate that I still have to find the antiderivate of something, so I just used the little $'$ that I know from finding the derivative.)**

$$f(x)=n^2 x^{n-1}$$
$$F(x)=(n^2)' (x^{n-1})'$$
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}n^3 (x^{n-1})'$$
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n} x^n$$
So basically I just always use the reverse of $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$, but apparently something is wrong.

Comment: Note the function above is $f(x)$. the antiderivative of f(x) with respect to variable x gives $nx^n +c$. $i.e$, $\int n^2 x^{n-1}dx = n^2 \int x^{n-1}dx $ If you want to consider the function as a variable of $n$, in that case you have to evaluate $\int n^2 x^{n-1}dn = \frac{x^{-1+n} \left(2-2 n \text{Log}[x]+n^2 \text{Log}[x]^2\right)}{\text{Log}[x]^3} + c$

Comment: WARNING: The antiderivative of a product is NOT the product of the antiderivatives (it looks like this is what you're doing in the second step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to integrate $n^2$. Why? It's not a function of $x$, but a constant. You can say
$$\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int n^2x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x=n^2\int x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x$$
Simply integrate the term inside the integrand, then multiply the $n^2$ back in. You'll see that you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between an antiderivative with respect to $n$ and an antiderivative with respect to $x$.

If the input to a function is $x$ and the output is $n^2 x^5$, and $n$ doesn't depend on $x$, then $n^3$ is a constant.  The antiderivative is $n^2 \dfrac{x^6}6 \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}\sum}$.

If the input to a function is $n$ and the output is $n^2 x^5$, and $x$ doesn't depend on $x$, then $x^5$ is a constant.  The antiderivative is $\dfrac{n^3} 3  \cdot x^5 \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}\sum}$.